# Compute this Hessian

Tags: convex-analysis, riemannian-geometry, hessian-matrix

Let $f$ be a smooth, real valued function on a complete Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ and $x_0\in M$. Define the function $\tilde f=f\circ Exp_{x_0}:T_{x_0}M\to \mathbb R$.

What is the Hessian of $\tilde f$, in terms of that of $f$ and characteristics of $(M,g)$?

Reason for this question: I am looking for a simple sufficient condition (ideally depending on bounds on the curvature of $(M,g)$) on $f$ so $\tilde f$ is convex.

Comment: What is the metric used on $T_{x_0}M$?

Comment: Identify $T_{x_0}M$ with $\mathbb R^n$, where $n$ is the dimension of $M$, and use the Euclidean structure inherited from $g$ (i.e., $T_{x_0}M$ is equipped with the dot product $\langle u,v\rangle = g_{x_0}(u,v)$, for all $u,v\in T_{x_0}M$).